# Параллельный запуск команд

Tags: bash

Есть код в котором команды выполняются одна за другой. Необходимо, чтобы они запускались параллельно, будто в разных терминалах

```
wipe -crf dir1
wipe -crf dir2
wipe -crf file
```

Comment: Амперссанд (`&`) в конце команд добавьте. правда не понимаю за чем. головки диска будут больше бегать и параллельно вполне возможно они будут выполняться дольше, чем по очереди

Comment: `nohup` если эти команды чего-то могут вывести. & сработает до первого IO с терминалом.

Comment: @0andriy команды с  `&`  могут спокойно продолжать работать, к примеру, `python -c $'import time\nwhile True:\n time.sleep(1)\n print(time.asctime())' &`. `nohup` полезен, если вы из сессии хотите выйти. Если терминал у вас всё ещё открыт, то `&`  может быть вполне достаточно (у меня TTIN сигнал при попытке чтения посылается процессу, но TTOU сигнал не посылается при выводе в терминал): [*"Оболочки часто отвергают заданное по умолчанию действие остановки SIGTTOU так, что фоновые процессы предоставят свой вывод по умолчанию управляющему терминалу. "*](https://goo.gl/cWfWPr)

Comment: [**Используйте GNU Parallel**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427419/237999). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
wipe -crf dir1 &
wipe -crf dir2 &
wipe -crf file &
```